# Type-hinting with local variables that have the same name conflict

Tags: python, type-hinting

In the example below, I have a warning that the type-hinting has been done incorrectly although I re-defined the variable `test`:
[image]

To reproduce the error, here is the code:

```
SOMETHING: bool = True
if something:
    test: list[str]
    test = ["1", "3", "twisted t"]
    del test
else:
    test: list[int]
    test = [1, 3, 7]
    del test
```

I'm using PyCharm.

```
    PyCharm 2022.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-222.3345.131, built on July 27, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.3+7-b469.32 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2030M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.chesterccw.excelreader (2022.2.2)
```

EDIT: as @MohamedYasser pointed out, putting the hint in the same line as the assigment doesn't show the message anymore. However, in some cases (unpacking a tuple), it's not possible. So there still is a problem to be solved :/

Comment: I get the same weird behavior in VSCode. The only thing that produces what I expected is actually not using the type hints, letting the IDE interpret from what the variable is being set to.

Comment: nvim produces a different behavior. Try to put the hint in the same line as the assignment and check if it still shows the message.

Comment: @MohamedYasser you are right, putting the hint in the same line as the assigment doesn't show the message anymore. However, in some cases (unpacking a tuple), it's not possible. So there still is a problem to be solved :/. I have edited my post to include your brilliant insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two different names.

What you're trying to do isn't valid. It's a type error. Even if you put the type hint on the same line as the assignment, [mypy will detect the error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ee410c1c8c38522a7ca238adb15f18c0).

You cannot create two variables with the same name and different static types in the same scope, or statically un-create a variable and create a new one with a different static type.

It doesn't matter that you put the annotations inside `if`/`else` blocks. Those don't have their own scope in Python. Functions, classes, and a few syntax constructs like list comprehensions and generator expressions will create a new scope, but arbitrary blocks don't have their own scope in Python.

It doesn't matter that you `del` the variables, either. `del` will unbind a variable when executed, but it doesn't end the variable's scope or make the variable stop existing, statically or dynamically.

Comment: I guess this actually makes sense. I can't really say it's a local variable just because it's in different parts of the `if` / `else` statement.